# How to display an option value of a GlusterFS server

Tags: glusterfs

How can I display a value of an option for a GluserFS server. [GlusterFS Documentation](https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Managing%20Volumes/) talks only about **setting option values**:

`gluster volume set`, e.g. `gluster volume set test-volume performance.cache-size 256MB`

There is no mention of inspecting option values currently in use. There were also several people asking similar question with no answer - is that really possible to not be able to display an option value in GlusterFS cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question when I was editing the docs for RHGS 3.1.2. :) The good news is, 'gluster volume get' has been implemented as of at least glusterfs version 3.7.9-7.

Docs for the Red Hat version are here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage/3.1/html-single/Administration_Guide/index.html

Hope this helps!